# Converting specific image to base64 string is incorrect

Tags: java, base64

I am trying to convert an image to a base64 String using the following code

```
public String base64Concert() throws Exception {
    String imageUrl = "https://www.anyhost.org/image/ThisGateway/ThisGatewayImage?imageName=IMG2975576618502471333.PNG";

    String getEncodedString = getBase64String(imageUrl);

    System.out.println("encoded String: " + getEncodedString);


}


// Image conversion

public String getBase64String(String imageUrl) throws Exception {
    byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new URL(imageUrl));
    String encodedString = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageBytes);

    return encodedString;

}
```

This works fine for any other images eg. http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png and I will get the correct base64 string and I can use it in html:

```
<div>
<p>This is a test</p>
<img src="data:image/png;base64, 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"/>
```

But with this specific image I want to convert I get a strange base64 encoded result that does not display when I put it in Html

```
<div>
<p>This is a test</p>
<img src="data:image/png;base64, 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"/>
```

I verified this result I got from the Java code with what is generated from this online tool, https://www.base64-image.de/, and the results is not the same. The result from the tool does work when I put it in html.

Unfortunately the image I am using is secured with certificates so I will not be able to share that URL.
The file is about 16MB, but I am not sure if size is the issue. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was using Resttemplate to make the initial call to get the image URL in the response. I included the .pfx certificates in this resttemplate call. However, when I make the second call using new URL() I did not include the certificates and I was retrieving a failed html response that I encoded.